How to use data validation to restrict values to 0 or less than a specified value in another cell?
I am trying to use data validation to restrict values in a cell. The cell cannot be blank and must have values that are either 0 or less than a value specified in another cell on a different sheet. I can't seem to find an option that works.
How to achieve this?

which spreadsheet software? There are differences. Edit your question and add that there, NOT in a comment.

And also, please put more details on where in the sheet you are applying the data validation to, and what's the other sheet and cell you want to compare it to.

Telling us what kind of data you are working with will give you better answer suited to your scenario (for example, whether you are allowed to enter negative value in the cell or not)

Assuming you are asking for Microsoft Excel, you need to use the Data Validation feature, which is available under the Data menu (look for an icon with a green-right icon and a stop icon).
Step 1: Select the cell where you want to apply the restriction
Step 2: Click on the data validation icon, and choose custom from dropdown.
Step 3: Formula to be used
=OR(C3=0, AND(C3>0, C3<Sheet2!C3))

If you want to allow negative value, use this formula
=OR(C3=0, C3<Sheet2!C3)

Apply the formula on the cell where the restriction needs to be applied. C3 on Sheet2 is where you define the value X (max value one can input).
Attaching images for your reference



Note: If you are using Google Sheet, go to Data > Data Validation. Here you need to use custom formula =OR(C3=0, AND(ISNUMBER(C3), A1<Sheet2!C3))


The cell must not be blank: A1<>""
The cell can be either 0 or less than a value specified in another cell: OR(A1=0, A1<B1)

Combined:
=AND(A1<>"",OR(A1<A1,A1=0))
It checks first if the cell is blank, then validates the entered value. Change A1 to your cell being validated, and B1 to the cell that is the limit of the value. Adjust the delimiter (comma or semicolon) to your localization.
